# Pandas comparing rows of dataframes and returning set based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
[in] print(testing_df.head(n=5))
print(product_combos1.head(n=5))

[out]
                     product_id  length
transaction_id                         
001                      (P01,)       1
002                  (P01, P02)       2
003             (P01, P02, P09)       3
004                  (P01, P03)       2
005             (P01, P03, P05)       3

             product_id  count  length
0            (P06, P09)  36340       2
1  (P01, P05, P06, P09)  10085       4
2            (P01, P06)  36337       2
3            (P01, P09)  49897       2
4            (P02, P09)  11573       2
```

I would like to return the `product_combos` rows with the highest frequency that are of `len(testing_df + 1)` and contain the `testing_df` strings within them. So for example, transaction_id 001 I would like to return `product_combos[3]` (only P09 though).

For the first part (making the comparison based solely on length) I tried:

```
# Return the product combos values that are of the appropriate length and the strings match
for i in testing_df['length']:
    for k in product_combos1['length']:
        if (i)+1 == (k):
            matches = list(k)
```

However, this returns the error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a list from a non-iterable like that. Try replacing `matches = list(k)` with `matches = [k]`.
Also those parentheses are redundant - you can replace `if (i)+1 == (k):` with `if i + 1 == k:`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the .append() method. I also recommend setting 'matches' to an empty list at the top so you don't get duplicates when you re-run a cell.

```
# Setup

testing_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['product_id','length'])
testing_df.product_id = [('P01',),('P01', 'P02')]
testing_df.length = [1,2]
product_combos1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['product_id','count','length'])
product_combos1.length = [3,1]
product_combos1.product_id = [('P01',),('P01', 'P02')]
product_combos1.count = [100,5000]

# Matching

matches = []
for i in testing_df['length']:
    for k in product_combos1['length']:
        if i+1 == k:
            matches.append(k)
```

Let me know if that works, or if there's anything else! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this did not work- however I was able to solve the issue using another method.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! It worked fine in my notebook with the example setup given. Glad to hear that you were able to solve the issue! Remember to post it as an answer when you get a chance, so other people coming to this post can reference.